# What's wrong with my K-Dane algorithm implementation?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

For the HackerRank challenge [The Maximum Subarray](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maxsubarray) we are supposed to implement the K_Dane algorithm for negative numbers as well.

Below is my C implementation, I've tried to figure out how to debug this, but haven't been successful in doing so, can anyone help me figure out the bugs in the code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long int t, n;
    scanf("%lld", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        long long int numbers[n], i;
        for(i = 0;i < n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%lld", &numbers[i]);
        }
        long long int contigoussum = numbers[0],crtsum = numbers[0], sum = numbers[0];
        for(i = 1;i < n;i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] + sum > sum)
            {
                sum += numbers[i];
            }

            crtsum += numbers[i];
            if(crtsum > contigoussum)
            {
                contigoussum = crtsum;
            }
            else
                crtsum = 0;
        }

        printf("%lld %lld\n", contigoussum, sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Though, I don't know all the test cases the code fails to work, but heres one I came up with:

*Input*

```
1
6
2 -1 2 3 4 -5
```

*Output*

```
7 11
```

*Real answer*: I suppose it's `10 11` as the max contigous sum could be for `[2 -1 2 3 4]`.

Comment: In which way wrong? Add an input, the expected output and the computed output to your question. Have you tried to trace a small example by using a debugger?

Comment: Well, I don't really know... The HackerRank doesn't tell me which test cases are wrong, and what are the test cases... @MrSmith42

Comment: So your code passes all your examples you used for testing?

Comment: @MrSmith42 I have added a test case which my code fails to work at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of this :

```
else
   crtsum = 0;
```

change it to this :

```
else if(crtsum <0)
    crtsum = 0;
```

[here](http://ideone.com/7BXWmV) is an online version of your working code.

Comment: That's great. That works for that test case, but I'm not sure why, yet my code still fails one test case, which I don't have...

Comment: @Nib I really have no idea, it is not my contest, it is probably your problem with big numbers and ... Beside that I just checked your profile and see that you rarely accept an answer, here and in ME. Its not really a good approach.

Comment: If my question isn't answered, then I don't accept an answer... @AliAmiri

Comment: @Nib it is your answer, but if you want to someone here like me take contest for you this is different situation. But as there is a saying in my language "kings knows whats better for them" :)

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer fails for all negative array

```
void calc(vector<int>& ar){
    int contigoussum = 0,crtsum = 0, sum = 0;
    int positive=0;
    int max=ar[0];

    for(int i = 0;i < ar.size();i++)
    {
        if(ar[i]>0)
            positive =1;
        else if (ar[i]>max)
            max=ar[i];
        if(ar[i] + sum > sum)
        {
            sum += ar[i];
        }

        crtsum += ar[i];
        if(crtsum > contigoussum)
        {
            contigoussum = crtsum;
        }
        else if(crtsum <0)
            crtsum = 0;
    }
    if(positive)
        cout<< contigoussum<<" "<<sum<<endl;
    else
        cout<< max<<" "<<max<<endl;             
}
```